# UnboundField Visibility in Infragistics

Tags: c#, infragistics

I have one Checkbox and XamTextEditor in XAML. Now, what I am trying to do is when I check a checkbox, the XamTextEditor will get visible. I have tried a lot but I am very new to Infragistics, so can you please help me?

This is my CheckBox and XamTextEditor XAML code :

```
<igDP:Field Name="CustomPath" Label="">
    <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings Width="60" AllowEdit="True" AllowResize="True"/>
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:Field>
<igDP:UnboundField Name="FolderName" Label="Folder Name" Width="Auto" Visibility="Visible">
    <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings Width="500" EditorType="{x:Type Editors:XamTextEditor}"></igDP:FieldSettings>
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>
```